# What is the difference between C++98 and C++11 SFINAE rules?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have read that SFINAE Rule is more simpler in C++11 than in C++98. In the book of Bjarne Stroustrup "A Tour of C++", it is noted that C++11 has a simpler and more general SFINAE rule. (Section 14.2.1 Item 39)

What is the difference between C++98 and C++11 SFINAE rules?

Comment: May I ask you why you need that?

Comment: http://www.bfilipek.com/2016/02/notes-on-c-sfinae.html